Add a references section with a very simple format
I just had a paper published in a journal, from an MS Word submission, and now want to put it in LaTeX and submit to arXiv.  The journal has a very simple reference format, like "(Smith 2020)" in the text, and a references section simply listed in alphabetical order.  Eg, a portion of the Reference section looks like this:

Andreotta AJ (2021) The hard problem of AI rights. AI & Soc. https://doi.org/10.1007/s00146-020-00997-x, Article, Google Scholar


Bhattacherjee M, Sinha S (2024) As you sow, so shall you reap: rethinking humanity in the age of artificial intelligence. AI & Soc. https://doi.org/10.1007/s00146-024-01983-3, Article, Google Scholar

I want to use a formal References section in the LaTeX version I submit to arXiv, in case they ever process files to extract references for some use and need an indication in the LaTeX source of where the references are.  However, I have very limited LaTeX knowledge, and when I try to use the "bibliography" functionality I either have to start the references with an item like "[Bha24]" or if I leave that out then the references get numbered.
I just want an alphabetical un-numbered list, as per the example above.  It sounds like a terrible solution to just create a bolded line "References" and then have a list of paragraphs with the references, because then I am not indicating in LaTeX that these are formally references.
Is there some way to use a formal LaTeX "bibliography" section for my references, but have the references simply listed in an alphabetical list (I can enter them in alphabetically order of course) without any "[Bha24]" or numbering or other additional formatting?
======= Update ==========
In addition to the very helpful answer of @mico and his comments below, I found I needed the following:

For most references like "\bibitem[(Waal 2008)]" one needs to put the citation in the body without a space, because the citation adds a preceding space before the "(", so need "...we are\citet{Waal:2008}", producing "we are (Waal 2008)".

For citations where the year follows the name, need to use "\bibitem[Collins(2024)]" without a space before the "(" because again the citation will add a space before the "(", and for these you can cite in the body including the space before the \citet as in "expressed by \citet{Collins:2024}", producing "expressed by Collins (2024)".

If you have an "et al." citation, there is no winning.  It will add a space before the "(", so as usual you add the \citet without a preceeding space as in "frontal cortex\citet{Einevoll:2019}".  However, sometimes it will also add an extra space after the "al.".  That is, if you write "\bibitem[(Einevoll et al. 2019)]" you will get "frontal cortex (Einevoll et al.~~2019)" with the "~" symbol used in this comment just to indicate the double space.  On the other hand, if you remove the space in the bibitem like "\bibitem[(Einevoll et al.2019)]" then it will not add a space after "al." and you will be short one space as in "frontal cortex (Einevoll et al.2019)".  My solution was to remove the "." and go with "\bibitem[(Einevoll et al 2019)]", which produces close to what one wants as "frontal cortex (Einevoll et al 2019)".



It looks like you don't want to learn how to use an external software tool, such as BibTeX, to create the bibliography programmatically and, instead, are willing to create it by hand. Please advise if this impression is incorrect.
You asked,

Is there some way to use a formal LaTeX "bibliography" section?

Yes, it's a LaTeX environment called thebibliography. You start it with
\begin{thebibliography}{n}

where n should be 9 if you have 9 or fewer bibliographic entries, 99 if you have between 10 and 99 bibliographic entries; etc. You end the bibliography section  with
\end{thebibliography}

You then populate the thebibiography environment with \bibitem statements. For instance,
\bibitem[Andreotta(2021)]{andreotta:2021} 
Andreotta AJ (2021) The hard problem of AI rights. AI \& Soc. 
\url{https://doi.org/10.1007/s00146-020-00997-x}, 
%Article, Google Scholar

\bibitem[Bhattacherjee and Sinha(2024)]{bhattacherjee-sinha:2024} 
Bhattacherjee M, Sinha S (2024) As you sow, so shall you reap: 
rethinking humanity in the age of artificial intelligence. 
AI \& Soc. \url{https://doi.org/10.1007/s00146-024-01983-3}, 
%Article, Google Scholar

Each \bibitem directive takes one optional argument, in square brackets, and one mandatory argument, in curly braces. The mandatory argument will be used in \cite directives in the body of the docment, and the optional argument will be used to show what the citation call-out should look like.
Note that since the thebibliography is created by hand, you are in charge of all formatting decisions as well.
Finally, be sure to load the natbib citation management package and to use \citet and \citep directives to create text-style and paranthetic-style citation call-outs in the body of the document.

A compilable example and its output:

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\usepackage{xurl} % allow linebreaks in long URL strings
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % create hyperlinks

\begin{document}

\dots as shown by \citet{andreotta:2021}.

\dots \citep{bhattacherjee-sinha:2024}.


\begin{thebibliography}{9} % start the bibliography section

\bibitem[Andreotta(2021)]{andreotta:2021} 
Andreotta AJ (2021) The hard problem of AI rights. AI \& Soc. 
\url{https://doi.org/10.1007/s00146-020-00997-x}, 
%Article, Google Scholar % not needed

\bibitem[Bhattacherjee and Sinha(2024)]{bhattacherjee-sinha:2024} 
Bhattacherjee M, Sinha S (2024) As you sow, so shall you reap: 
Rethinking humanity in the age of artificial intelligence. 
AI \& Soc. \url{https://doi.org/10.1007/s00146-024-01983-3}, 
%Article, Google Scholar % not needed

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}


Addendum to address the OP's follow-up questions and comments.

I must confess that I don't understand the premise of the follow-up questions. I thought your query was about how to set up a supposedly simple hand-made bibliography in an arXiv-destined version of an already-published piece. The only -- actually not so simple -- complication was that you also wanted to preserve the use of authoryear-style citation call-outs in the body of the document. For that, I suggested you employ the natbib package and its \citet and \citep commands.

Your follow-up questions strongly suggest that you not only want to generate authoryear-style citation call-outs but also want to limit the scope of the hyperlinks to just the year portions, à la journal house style. ("The format of the journal is to link from the year only".) Why follow journal house style here? If anyone is going to bother to compare the arXiv- and journal-published versions of your piece, are they really going to become confused because the extent of the hyperlinks of the citation call-outs isn't identical across the two documents? I certainly hope not. After all, they're not going to be bothered by differences across the documents in font shapes, font sizes, line widths, and vertical spacing between lines either, are they?

However, if this issue really bothers you, I suggest you adopt the solution provided by @Aubrey in her answer to the query How to hyperlink only the year part when using natbib and hyperref. (This answer dates back to 2013. I checked that it still works in 2024.) Just copy everything from \usepackage{etoolbox} to \makeatother into your document's preamble (after loading natbib) and recompile your document.



Thanks, this is close.  However, two odd things.  One, I must include round brackets in bibitem or it generates several errors.  That is, "\bibitem[(2024)]{Bhattacherjee:2024}" works, but not "\bibitem[2024]{Bhattacherjee:2024}".  The format of the journal is to link from the year only, I guess for less blue text in the body of the paper.  So I need to be able to have a citation like "(Bhattacherjee and Sinha 2024)" with the link just from "2024".  You can see this in the journal paper linked in the first sentence of my question.  Can I set up a citation without round brackets?

The second thing is that I am getting an extra space before the citation in the body, whatever that citation is. So for example "author (2024)" but with two spaces before the "(", one extra to the space in the text. [SOLVED: I found the solution is simply to make the citation with no preceding space, e.g. in the LaTeX source like "As stated by\citet{ex24}"]

@LivingInternet - Please see the addendum I posted to address your follow-up questions.

Hi @mico, I want the link to be just from the year not only to follow the journal, but because readability is much better.  Complex ideas are greatly enhanced by readability.  References are subsidiary.  Having the text studded by long bright blue reference links significantly detracts from the readability, imho.  I tried your suggestion, and ran into more cascading errors.  I am going to give up on that.  Your first suggestion is most of what I want, I have a formal bibliography.  I will simply write out the references in the text, no links.  People can scroll down to References if desired.

@LivingInternet - If you don't want long distracting color strings in the citation call-outs, just replace allcolors=blue with citecolor=black (or allcolors=black). That way, you're still providing hyperlink convenience to you readers.

Fyi, another reason to allow the citation to be whatever text you want, and not require it to have round brackets.  I have a sentence that reads "...extension of Searle’s test (1980)".  Of course, one does not want the citation to include all of "Searle’s test (1980)".  The word "test" should not be in the citation.  On reflection, I wonder why these libraries were written to mandate that the citation text include round brackets.  Seems an odd controlling requirement.  If they had been written to allow any text the author wished to put in \bibitem then there would be no issues.

Thanks @mico, if I use that, can I still have blue links elsewhere, that is within the references themselves?  Within the references themselves, I want links to be blue to the DOI, article, and Google scholar.  Can I have them be black in the body, and blue in the references?

@LivingInternet - I am in absolutely no position to speculate as to how or why various citation call-out systems came about. Sorry.

@LivingInternet - The hyperref package provides (at least) seven ....color options. You can definitely set citecolor=black but also urlcolor=blue and linkcolor=blue.

Thanks.  The following is creating an "Option clash for package hyperref", any ideas why?
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

Never, ever load a package more than once. For sure, loading a package four [4!!] times is nothing but an open invitation for disaster. You need to execute either \usepackage{hyperref} \hypersetup{colorlinks, citecolor=black, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue} or, more directly, \usepackage[colorlinks, citecolor=black, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}. You should still run \usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib} and  \usepackage{xurl}, of course.

Aha, that simple mistake of loading more than once is behind other issues I was having too.  Thanks.  And the link colors now work.  Everything is working, thanks much.
